# windows azure AspNetSqlMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles

I am working on an ASP.NET application that uses the AspNetSqlMembershipProvider for the authentication mechanism.

I am transferring the application to a cloud application in order to deploy it on windows azure.

Do I have to change the authentication mechanism that I use or will the AspNetSqlMembershipProvider will work normally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  have no need to change the Authentication Mechanism for the reason of deployment. Just make the local machine database scripts to run on the sql azure database. Everything should be work same as you are doing authentication on local development machine.

Check these links to know regarding this deployment of sql authentication or database script etc:

[Trying to deploy Asp.Net Memebership database to SQL Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047295/trying-to-deploy-asp-net-memebership-database-to-sql-azure)
[Updated ASP.net scripts for use with Microsoft SQL Azure](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2006191)

After installing the scripts, just change the connection string in the webconfig that provide the authentication through database.

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="LocalSqlServer"
         connectionString="you azure connection string"  
         providerName="Provider..." />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't change the authentication mechanism, just use the [Universal Providers](https://nuget.org/packages/System.Web.Providers) and it will work normally.